# How to count the number of rows from the last non-zero value (or to the next, if the lattest greater than k)

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I've got a data like below:

```
ex <- structure(list(id = 1:20, V1 = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -20L))
```

Now I need to create a new column that would count the number of rows from the latest non-zero value. One additional condition is that if that number is greater than `k` then we would count the number of rows before the next non-zero value (with `-` sign). So assuming `k = 10` the output would look like below:

```
structure(list(id = 1:20, V1 = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), counter = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -20L))
```

What's the efficient way to do this using `tidyverse` packages, if possible?

Comment: Yes, it is. As I assumed `k = 10` after the row where `count` equals 10 the intented behavior is to count back to the NEXT 0 value.

Answer (score 4):

A base R approach with `ave`, where we first calculate number of rows from the last non-zero value and then for values greater than `k` we reverse the index position and add the negative sign to get sequence in -2, -1 order.

```
ave(ex$V1, cumsum(ex$V1 != 0) , FUN = function(x) {
     inds <- seq_along(x) - 1
     ifelse(inds > k, -rev(inds) - 1, inds)
})

#[1]  0  1  2  3  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 -2 -1  0  1  2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use calculate step as difference versus lag id, additional condition on value could be added and then build sequences with conditions whether it is reverse or not

```
  Steps <- ex%>%
  rbind(c(nrow(ex)+1,1)) %>%
  filter(sign(V1)!=0) %>%
  mutate(step= id-c(1,(lag(id)[-1])))

 c <- c()
 k<-10
 for (i in 1:nrow(Steps)){
 c<- c(c,c(0:max(0,min(Steps[i,3], k)-1)))
 if(Steps[i,3]> k){
   c <- c(c, (k-Steps[i,3]+1):-1)
  }
 }
c<-c[ex$id]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
ex <- structure(list(id = 1:20, V1 = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -20L))

library(tidyverse)

k_LIMIT <- 10
ex %>%
  mutate(my_group_var = cumsum(V1)) %>%  
  group_by(my_group_var) %>%
  mutate(want = ifelse((row_number() - 1) > k_LIMIT,
                       -(max((row_number() - 1)) - (row_number() - 1) + 1),
                       (row_number() - 1))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-my_group_var)

# A tibble: 20 x 3
#      id    V1  want
#   <int> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1     1     0
# 2     2     0     1
# 3     3     0     2
# 4     4     0     3
# 5     5     9     0
# 6     6     0     1
# 7     7     0     2
# 8     8     0     3
# 9     9     0     4
#10    10     0     5
#11    11     0     6
#12    12     0     7
#13    13     0     8
#14    14     0     9
#15    15     0    10
#16    16     0    -2
#17    17     0    -1
#18    18     1     0
#19    19     0     1
#20    20     0     2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
k <- 10
setDT(ex)[,    grp := cumsum(V1 != 0)
    ][, counter := seq_len(.N) - 1, grp
     ][counter > k, counter := -as.numeric(rev(seq_len(.N))), grp
      ][, grp := NULL][]
#.   id V1 counter
# 1:  1  1       0
# 2:  2  0       1
# 3:  3  0       2
# 4:  4  0       3
# 5:  5  9       0
# 6:  6  0       1
# 7:  7  0       2
# 8:  8  0       3
# 9:  9  0       4
#10: 10  0       5
#11: 11  0       6
#12: 12  0       7
#13: 13  0       8
#14: 14  0       9
#15: 15  0      10
#16: 16  0      -2
#17: 17  0      -1
#18: 18  1       0
#19: 19  0       1
#20: 20  0       2
```